# Google drive api: Integrate with Drive UI - Install URL/drive.install not supported anymore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api

I have a ASP.Net Web application which uses Google drive api v3. I need to integrate it with the Google Drive UI (So that its available in the right click  open with option)
As a part of the requirements I need to prompt the user to install the application.
I am trying to follow the documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/install

However even after numerous attempts of reinstalling the google drive api v3 i don't see the scope "drive.install".
In addition, in developers console I do not see the Install URL  textbox.

As per the document :
"Install URL

You can use the Install URL if you wish to redirect your users to a special URL the first time they open your app from Drive."

Also when I just try and browse with the suggested request(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install) I get 404

I wonder if its even supported now?
Is my only option now to list the app in the Chrome Web Store ? I hope not..

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk#authentication), *Do not select Automatically show OAuth 2.0 consent screen when users open my application from Google Drive. This feature is deprecated. All authorization requests must be initiated by the application.* You may want to check this [Authorization documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth). Your application must use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/#google-sign-in), some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

Comment: I am using OAuth 2.0. It still doesn't help. I wonder if install is only supported for marketplace sdk.